# Is the integral of the product of separable functions equal to the product of their integrals

Tags: integration

For two continuous functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ let their integrals be given by:

$$I_1 = \int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$I_2 = \int g(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$$

Then under which conditions is it true that

$$\int \int f(x)\cdot g(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x = I_1 \cdot I_2$$

That is to say that the integral of their product is equal to the product of their integrals?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2251028/111946

Comment: The duplicate question is actually about a completely different thing, since here we are integrating over two variables. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever $\displaystyle\iint|f(x)g(y)|<\infty$. By Tonelli, you can check if both $\displaystyle\int|f(x)|<\infty$ and $\displaystyle\int|g(y)|<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is true when,

$$I_1=\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$ and $$I_2=\int g(y) \mathrm{d}y$$ exist and both are finite then,

$$I_1\cdot I_2= \int\int g(y)f(x)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$

Must exist.