# Can someone explain if $\iint f(x)g(y)\,dx,dy=\int f(x)\,dx*\int g(y)\,dy$?

Tags: integration

Question is as stated above. Can someone explain if (and how) $$\iint f(x)g(y)\,dx,dy=\int f(x)\,dx*\int g(y)\,dy$$

I found this website, but I don't get why they use $x\leq y\leq b$. It makes a bit more sense (in my mind), to have $0\leq y\leq x$, but I still don't undersand how to finish/solve this logic.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496674/is-the-integral-of-the-product-of-separable-functions-equal-to-the-product-of-th) may also be of interest

Comment: @B.Mehta The first question is not a duplicate : here we have two variables instead of one.

Comment: I mainly linked that as the second is marked as a duplicate of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\in L^{1}({\bf{R}}^{n})$ and $g\in L^{1}({\bf{R}}^{m})$, then by Fubini Theorem, $fg:(x,y)\rightarrow f(x)g(y)$ is such that $fg\in L^{1}({\bf{R}}^{n}\times{\bf{R}}^{m})\cong L^{1}({\bf{R}}^{n+m})$ and that
\begin{align*}
\iint_{{\bf{R}}^{n+m}}f(x)g(y)dxdy&=\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}\left(\int_{{\bf{R}}^{m}}f(x)g(y)dy\right)dx\\
&=\int_{{\bf{R}}^{m}}\left(\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}f(x)g(y)dx\right)dy,
\end{align*}
and we have 
\begin{align*}
\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}\left(\int_{{\bf{R}}^{m}}f(x)g(y)dy\right)dx&=\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}f(x)\left(\int_{{\bf{R}}^{m}}g(y)dy\right)dx\\
&=\left(\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{{\bf{R}}^{m}}g(y)dy\right).
\end{align*}