# Given two definite integrals, find the integral of the product of their integrands

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This question was on a calculus 1 test:

Given $\int_1^5 f(x) dx = 5$ and $\int_1^5 g(x) dx = \frac{2}{3}$,

Evaluate $\int_5^1 f(x) g(x) dx$

The following was my (naive) approach (using properties more suited to limits):

$\int_5^1 f(x) g(x) dx = -\int_1^5 f(x) g(x) dx = -5\bigl(\frac{2}{3}\bigr) = -\frac{10}{3}$

But I'm unsure whether integrals distribute over products in that way, and think the question was likely misprinted. However, I was awarded full marks for that answer. So is there a way that integral of a product can be the product of their integrals for unknown functions?

Comment: In general, $\int f \cdot g \neq \int f \cdot \int g$. So you should not have been given credit for your answer.

Comment: I'm thinking the problem contains some kind of typo. I would not expect any particular way of getting $\int fg$ just from knowing $\int f$ and $\int g$. Otherwise, things like H\"older's inequality or worse would be absolutely trivial (and we would have an equality instead).

Comment: The given information is not sufficient to work out the product integral. I'm guessing your teacher realized that and gave you full marks because it was their error.

Comment: It’s only true in rare cases. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250993/when-the-integral-of-products-is-the-product-of-integrals

Comment: I'll bet a chocolate fish that the last integrand was supposed to be $f(x)+g(x).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments point out, the integral cannot be evaluated with only the given information and the property used only holds true in [rare cases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250993/when-the-integral-of-products-is-the-product-of-integrals).

So, $\int_5^1 f(x) g(x) dx = -\int_1^5 f(x) g(x) dx \ne -\int_1^5f(x)dx \int_1^5g(x)dx = -5\bigl(\frac{2}{3}\bigr) = -\frac{10}{3}$

Comment: Answer added so people don't waste further time trying to look into it.