# Why product of integral of exponential can be double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

Please help understand why the square $I^2$ of the integral of exponential$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} exp(\frac {-1}{2\sigma^2} \, x^2) \, dx   \tag{1}
$$

can be expressed as double integral as in (2).
$$
\begin{align}
I^2 &= 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} exp(\frac {-1}{2\sigma^2} \, x^2) \, dx 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} exp(\frac {-1}{2\sigma^2} \, y^2) \, dy 
\\
&=
\iint_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
exp \Bigl(  \frac {-1}{2\sigma^2} \, (x^2 + y^2) \Bigl) \, \, dx \, dy 
\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

I believe the product of integrals can be double integral because of exponential but could not understand how it can be transformed as such.

[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf)

> [image]

### Related

- [When the integral of products is the product of integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250993/when-the-integral-of-products-is-the-product-of-integrals)

Comment: A definite integral returns a number, no matter what variable is used. So writing, say $e^{-x^2}$ or $e^{-y^2}$ in the integrand doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function $f$ can be separated into the product of two functions $X$ and $Y$ - where each of them only rely on $x$ and $y$ respectively - you can split the double integral like that.

$$\iint f(x, y) dy dx = \iint X(x) Y(y) dydx = \int X(x) \int Y(y) dy dx = \int X(x) dx \int Y(y) dy$$

since $X(x)$ and $dx$ are all constants when we integrate $Y(y) dy$. $X(x) = ce^{-x^{2}}$ and $Y(y) = ce^{-y^{2}}$ is your case.

When the integral is squared, there should be two $x$'s then change one into $y$ (Because the name of the parameters does not matter).